# how to store and retrieve multiple decision trees in matlab

Tags: matlab, object, struct, classification, decision-tree

I have a for loop that generates a single decision tree each time and later on in the program I need to apply all the decision trees to the testing data (the decision trees are NOT combined in an ensemble). I tried to store them in an array of structures but when I am applying them to the test data I have the following error:

> (Undefined function 'predict' for input arguments of type 'struct'.).

I know that the tree generated is an object but how you can store and retrieve multiple objects in MATLAB?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [mcve] with your code, explain why it does not work for you and what the expected results are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually the arrays of objects would do (the only thing is that the class needs a default constructor in order to allocate the space).

So, the safest way is to use a cell array. The code would be something along the lines of:

```
%'"N" is the size of your problem'
dtrees = cell(1,N);
for k = 1:N
        %'Create the decision tree "obj"'
        %'...'
        dtrees{k} = obj;
end;

%'...'

%'Later iterate in the cell array'
for k = 1:N
        obj = dtrees{k};
        %'Now do stuff with "obj"'
        %'...'
end;
```

Comment: Thanks CST-Link for your answer and the example

Comment: @HannaK Glad that I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You use cell arrays. 
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-cell-array.html
they can store pretty much whatever.

Comment: The essential parts of the Answer is: You use cell arrays. It answers the question "how you can store and retrieve multiple objects in MATLAB?" The llink is merely a reference to the documentation for cell arrays, in case she/he needs it in his implementation.